# Can a mongodb TTL index be used for queries?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

A collection has two indices:

- A) `{ date: 1 }`
- B) `{ date: -1 }` with TTL

I removed index A because the same index already exists as index B, albeit with a TTL and in opposite sort order.

[Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#support-for-queries) says:

> A TTL index supports queries in the same way non-TTL indexes do.

The opposite sort order should not matter since mongodb can traverse the index in either direction.

However, the index B is not used according to `$indexStats` and it is in fact not used because the query now takes considerably longer to execute.

Why isn't index B used?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Please update your question to include the output of `explain(true)` for the query. This will show all candidate plans considered.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb  could  create  indexes  both  asc  and desc on One  field  .
such as :

```
> db.ttt.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 4,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 5,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.ttt.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": -1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 5,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 6,
    "ok" : 1
}
>
```

but  can not change  the Index  if  you try  to  recreate  it .
you  can  use  `getIndexes()`  to  see  your  Indexes  , and  `dropIndex()`  to  recreate  it .

the  TTL  INDEXES  also  worked  as  non-TTL indexes do.

Why isn't index B used?

this is  accorrding your  query and Index optimizer .
if you have  more better  index  , Of course willnot use  worse  one .
you can show me  more  about  your query  and Indexes .

Comment: Index B was the only index that started with `date`, so IMO it was the only appropriate index to be used.

Comment: @Manuel Can you please update your question with the `explain(true)` output and version of MongoDB server? We need those details to see what the query planner considered (and potentially explain your outcome).

Comment: @Manuel  how  do you know  ,show the result  of the command .